# Inconsistent name resolution in email "To" field for contacts in Outlook / Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, contacts

I'm seeing some really strange, inconsistent behaviour with how the browser-based Outlook / Office 365 resolves names for email addresses of contacts when I enter them into the "To" field for new emails.

I have some people who I've had set up as contacts in Outlook for some time now and that I regularly email as follows:

- **Polly Example** - polly.example@hotmail.com
- **Nathan Sample** - nathansample@me.com
- **Julien Etc** - julien_etc@hotmail.com
- **Rachael Lorem-Ipsum** - rachaelloremimpsum@gmail.com
- **Ed Blah** - edblah@gmail.com

I have a piece of text that I usually paste into the "To" field of a new email which adds all of their names at once, which works quite happily with the Outlook **desktop** application, but behaves all kinds of strange when I past it into the "To" field of an email in the browser based Outlook:

```
Polly Example [polly.example@hotmail.com];
Nathan Sample [nathansample@me.com];
Julien Etc [julien_etc@hotmail.com];
Rachael Lorem-Ipsum [rachaelloremimpsum@gmail.com];
Ed Blah [ed.blah@gmail.com]
```

The weird thing that I don't understand is that this currently resolves to a bunch of "pills" in the "To" field of the browser-based Outlook that look like this (apologies for the ASCII art):

```
(P) polly.example@hotmail.com X
(N) Nathan Sample [nathansample@me.com] X
(JJ) Julien Etc <julien_etc@hotmail.com> X
(R) Rachael Lorem-Ipsum [rachaelloremimpsum@gmail.com] X
(E) Ed Blah <ed. blah@gmail. com> (ed.blah@gmail.com) <ed.blah@gmail.com> X
```

Note - Nathan and Rachael both appear unresolved in red text, whereas the other 3 are blue text, even though all 5 definitely exist in my contacts.

I can't see any differences between the contacts in browser UI, so I don't understand where these differences are coming from. The questions I have in my head are:

- What is Outlook doing to resolve these names?
- Why do some have the "`firstname lastname`" and some don't?
- Why do some have the "`<email@address>`" and some don't?
- Why does Julien's "pill" have "JJ" whereas all the others only have one letter?
- Why can't it even resolve some of them?
- And what on *earth* is going on with Ed Blah?

But ultimately, I guess what I want to know is:

- Is there a predictable (and ideally, documented) way that the browser-based Outlook decides what to show in the "To" field when given a recipient in the format "firstname lastname [email@address]?"

**Update**

I've worked out why *some* of them didn't work properly - there's hidden characters in the text. In my case it was the Unicode Left-To-Right mark (U+220E) - for example `Nathan Sample ? [nathansample@me.com]?;`. Removing these made Nathan resolve as `(NN) Nathan Sample <nathansample@me.com> X`. That also fixed Rachael Lorem-Ipsum.

I'm still not sure why Polly only shows her email address and not "firstname lastname ", or why Ed's name resolves to such a weird value.